# Windows Phone Emulator loses connection

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator, parallels

I am running Windows 10 Education from a Macbook Pro, 2,7 GHz Intel Core i5, 8GB ram running OS X 10.11 using Parallels Desktop 11.

I have spend the last two days trying to get Visual Studio 2015 to run the Windows phone emulators properly (More precisely: Mobile Emulator 10.0.10240.0 WVGA 4 inch 512MB). Managed to solve most, but now stuck with the emulator being very unreliable mainly giving me the following errors:

> The connection to 169.254.17.107:8117 has been lost. Debugging will be aborted.

or

> The emulator couldn't determine the host IP address, which is used to communicate with the guest virtual machine.
>   Some functionality may be disabled.

I can't find a pattern because sometimes it happens while the application is deploying - sometimes after it has loaded perfectly and I was able to use the emulator. Every now and then, after getting an error, I simply run the application again right away and it will work ok, until next time i need to run it.

- The virtual switch in Hyper-V is set to *Interal* and I have also tried *External* and *Private*.
- I have tried setting the MAC type to static for the network adapter under settings in Hyper-V.
- Tried deleting the emulators and all virtual switches.
- Tried disabling and enabling the virtual switch in Network Sharing.

Some of the guides and posts elsewhere about similar problems are a bit outdated (Running Windows 8 and Parallels 8 ect.) Can anyone help me make the emulators work every time with my setup?